# Searching for a data table within a directory?

Tags: asp.net, search

I'm trying to change the testimonials on our site. (Our web developer is out of the picture.) This is what I find in the code for where the testimonials are.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="testimonials">
         <ItemTemplate>
           <p class="testimonial">"<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %>"</p>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
```

My research so far has told me there should be a table(?)(dataitem?) somewhere called "Text" with the testimonials listed. It is my understanding that the "asp:Repeater" function repeats a specified format for every item in the list/table. That is all fine. I only need to change the text of the testimonials, which I believe are in this "Text" table or list.

I don't know how to search for this within the website directory. I've downloaded FileZilla, Kompozer, SeaMonkey and Firebug. If any of those programs can help, I will use them, but any way will do.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to search the variety of files and folders within the directory for the table/lists of testimonials. I gave the details at the beginning in case I'm missing something or misguided about the concept.

Answer (score 0):

DataItem is the data source bound to it.  Text is a property within the row of the data source.  Look for a `Repeater.DataSource = X` line, or a `DataSourceID="X"` on the repeater's markup.  That will identify the data source.

Comment: I have this line:

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="testimonials">.

I thought the ID="testimonials" referred to the formatting, but I did look for any files named "testimonials" within the website's files, and found nothing. Could it simply be the object's(list/table) name within a particular file? If so, how can I search for that without going through each of the files of our site?

Comment: id is the id of the control only.  It has nothing to do with CSS or any other files.  Nothing about the repeater itself would define anything related to the testimonials, but would most likely be in the .aspx.cs or .aspx.vb file, where it would pull in the testimonials.